# Next JS Browser support for Image and Script components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cross-browser, nextjs-image

Are **`Image`** and **`Script`** components from Next JS supported on all browsers including IE?

As per nextjs [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features) they've mentioned that Next JS supports all the browsers but it doesn't tell explicitly mentions the support for **`Image`** and **`Script`** component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: They're supported as well. Internally, Next.js just ends up converting those components to `<img>` and `<script>` elements, respectively.